# Got the black rectangle box when I use the command \fcolorbox

Tags: color

I just started to use `TeXstudio` and do not know why I got the black rectangle box when I use the command `\fcolorbox`

```
\documentclass[letterpaper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{latexsym,amsfonts,amssymb,amsmath,amsthm}
\usepackage[usenames]{color}
\usepackage[dvips]{graphicx}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{marvosym,bm,wasysym,mathrsfs,keystroke,manfnt,fancybox}

\begin{document}
$$\setlength{\fboxrule}{0.9pt}
\fcolorbox[rgb]{1.00,0.00,1.00}{1.00,1.00,1.00}{
\begin{tabular}{l}
A non-exact differential equation

\end{tabular}
}
$$
\end{document}
```

Once I remove the command `\fcolorbox`, then everything is ok??

I also encountered this problem when using `pdfTeX` in `WinEdt`.

Comment: that is to be expected if your viewer does not support colour, or if you are using the wrong driver option (which is normally set by default) impossible to tell from your fragment. Note that in latex you shouldn't use `$$` `\fcolorbox` does not need to be in math at all, and you are missing `%` after `{` and `\end{tabular}` (unless you intend to have a space either side of the tabular inside the box)

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with `\documentclass{...}`, the required `\usepackage`'s, `\begin{document}`, and `\end{document}`. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for TeX.SX users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

Comment: Based on the log, Texstudio also uses pdftex to compile which explain why I saw the same error when using Winedt with PdfTex.

Comment: I added the full code to the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the `[dvips]` option to `graphicx`: it's incompatible with `pdflatex`, and anyway, the graphicx package knows which driver to use.

Also, you should load `xcolor` in the place of `color`, in which  case the `[usenames]` option is the default.

Last, not least, don't use the plain TeX syntax `$$ … $$` for displayed equations. It can result in bad spacing. Use the LaTeX syntax `\[ … \]` instead.[image]

Comment: Amazing simple fix and extra tips! Thank you so much!

Comment: You're welcome. Always glad to give a hand!